# Views AJAX Submit is removing my custom classes

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, views

I have custom jQuery that I've added to views filters to my ajax view. When a user selects certain criteria a slideDown and addClass event is triggered and a new set of filters is shown. You can view it here:

https://www.feedingmatters.org/helpful-books

When I click submit the classes that are added to my elements are removed by Drupal. This causes the elements to display: none and now the users can no longer see their filter trail. How can I either stop Drupal from clearing my addClass? The filters need to remain visible so long as the correct criteria are selected.

Note: I tried [views dependent filters](https://drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters) but it doesn't work as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this recently in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371438/ajax-affecting-jquery-document-load-on-ajax-form/23391562?noredirect=1#comment35836264_23391562)

The answer is to wrap your jQuery in a Drupal Behaviour so that the classes are not removed on every ajax request. Because your current jQuery is probably only run on the first page load.

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

        // Put your jQuery Code Here

  }
};
})(jQuery);
```